# an mpi error: invalid tag value is -1

Tags: mpi

I'm working on mpi code and i had an error about tag. I was using MPI_ANY_tag. When i had this error, i replaced the tag by zero and it didn't produce any thing at all. Can any body tell me the reason

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>
using namespace std;
void ParaStochSimulator::first_reacsimulator()
{
if (mnprocess_id != 0)/*worker node*/
{
    PrepareRun();
    //SimulateSingleStep();
    //PostProcessRun();
    CalculateAllHazardValues();
    sent_taus = calc_tau();
    std::cout << "tau =" << sent_taus << std::endl;
    MPI_Send(&sent_taus, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /*FireTransition(min_mu, long p_nEnabledness = 1);*/

}
else if (mnprocess_id = 0)/*master*/ 
{
    /*SimulateSingleRun();*/
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&sent_taus, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    std::cout << sent_taus << std::endl;

MPI_Reduce(&sent_taus, &min_rec_taus, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0,       MPI_COMM_WORLD);
std::cout << min_rec_taus << std::endl;


} 
ParaStochSimulator::~ParaStochSimulator()
{
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You can only use MPI_ANY_TAG when receiving, not when sending. Think twice and it will get clear!
if(mnprocess_id = 0) Should be "==" !
The Reduce in the Master is unmatched in the Workers.

Comment: what do you mean by unmatched in worker? what exactly is unmatched the root is 0 as the receiver rank

Comment: I mean I see no call to MPI_Reduce in the workers. maybe it is hidden in CalculateHazardValues?

Comment: @GeorgBisseling You should post that comment as an answer response to this question because it fully solves the problem (thanks, by the way!).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `MPI_ANY_TAG` when receiving, not when sending.

Additionally `if(mnprocess_id = 0)` should be `if(mnprocess_id == 0)`. The `MPI_Reduce` in the main is unmatched in the workers.

I see no call to `MPI_Reduce` in the workers. Maybe it is hidden in `CalculateHazardValues`?